# Button to change background color

Tags: javascript, background-color

I wrote this short code to display a button that changes the background color to blue. The background color changes before I even click the button, and I'm just not sure why, shouldn't the background be white by default until I click the button?

```
//function to change background color
function changeBg(color) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// goBlue closure
var goBlue = changeBg("blue");

// create button
var blueButton = document.createElement("button");
blueButton.innerHTML = "Blue";

// add button to page
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(blueButton);

//add event listener
blueButton.addEventListener("click", goBlue);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your post but you should stop using "var" and use "let". 
I don't see what the point of var is considering the variable has a global scope and your code would be the same as not typing "var" at all.

"let" is better since it creates a "block-scoped local variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because on line 7 you're calling the function!

```js
var whatever = changeBg("blue") // <<<< Bam! BG is now blue
// and the value of whatever is undefined since the function is void
```

what you want is perhaps:

```js
const EL_body = document.querySelector("body");
const EL_btn = document.createElement("button");
const changeBodyBg = (color) => EL_body.style.backgroundColor = color;

EL_body.append(EL_btn);
EL_btn.innerHTML = "Blue";
EL_btn.addEventListener("click", () => changeBodyBg("blue"));
```

Above just for simplicity sake I used better function naming and a different syntax with [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you would have exactly this edits:

```js
// REMOVE LINE 7 and...

blueButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeBg("blue")
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I was just trying to set this up using a Closure - sorry if that wasn't clear! I just gave this another shot and the reason it wasn't working was because the function needed this return thing:

`return function() { document.body.style.backgroundColor = color; };`

I was using this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Just to add to this though, thank you! The function syntax definitely seems a lot more practical..

Answer (score 0):

`var goBlue = changeBg("blue");` will immediately invoke background color change.

Instead, try to pass changeBg to anonymous function in event listener

```
function changeBg(color) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// create button
var blueButton = document.createElement("button");
blueButton.innerHTML = "Blue";

// add button to page
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(blueButton);

blueButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  changeBg("blue")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've called the function `changeBg` and you are assigning the return value(which is undefined) of function `changeBg` to `goBlue`  variable.

```
var goBlue = changeBg("blue");
```

If you want to change the color on click of a button then you need to add `addEventListener`.

```js
//function to change background color
function changeBg(color) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// create button
var blueButton = document.createElement("button");
blueButton.textContent = "Blue";

// add button to page
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(blueButton);

//add event listener
blueButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  changeBg("blue");
});
```