# Select Row with Div onClick

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble selecting all 5 Div's in the same row with the following structure (I can't modify the HTML and I can only use JS, no jQuery):

```
<div id="board-container">
  <div id="board">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="exa"></div>
      <div class="exa"></div>
      <div class="exa"></div>
      <div class="exa"></div>
      <div class="exa"></div>
    </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```

When you click the following should happen:

No click

[image]

onClick

[image]

Any idea or suggestion?
Thanks!

*Edit

Sorry for my bad explanation. The idea is similar to that solution but I need to be able to select only one row because I have more than one, and I only need to be able to change the backgroud color of the one I select or click on.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR2ag.png)

Comment: Question is unclear. You can select all .exa that are direct children of .row with `document.querySelectorAll('.row > .exa')`. No idea what your question about the click is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button to change background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66809328/button-to-change-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear, but I assume that you want to change the **Background color** for the **Row**, whenever you clicked on any of the elements inside the Row, if that is the case then you should do something like this and please let me know if that is not the case.

Demo:

```js
    var parentEle = document.querySelector("#board");
    var rowChildren = document.querySelectorAll(".exa");

    rowChildren.forEach(function(element, index){
        console.log("Clicked on: " + index);
        console.log(element);
        element.addEventListener("click", function (){
            console.log("Changeing the background color for enter ROW");
            parentEle.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor  = "yellow";
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack28</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="board-container">
    <div id="board">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="exa">A</div>
            <div class="exa">B</div>
            <div class="exa">C</div>
            <div class="exa">D</div>
            <div class="exa">E</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color of the divs with the class exa in the row by clicking the boxes use something like this.

```
$("#board-container #board").click(function() {
$('.exa').css('background', 'yellow');
alert("clicked");
});
```

or change this

```
$(this).css('background', 'yellow');
```

to change only elements with .exa in that row to change background color.

I have added an event handler because you do not say how its clicked.